Guidewire Debug Server Failed
We are moving from version 9.x to Cloud version for insurance suite. JAVA_HOME is pointing to jdk 11.22 and IDEA_HOME is pointing to the correct version of IntelliJ IDEA . Studio comes up, but on starting the debug server encountering the below issue
"java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 5: etc\C:\GW\CC\claimcenter\modules\configuration\build\idea\webapp\WEB-INF\jetty.xml
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.FS.toPath(FS.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.BaseHome.getPath(BaseHome.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.StartArgs.resolveExtraXmls(StartArgs.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.processCommandLine(Main.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
    at com.guidewire.commons.jetty.GWServerJettyServerMain.main(GWServerJettyServerMain.java:62)"

Attempted to clear the .gradle from both application and user directories, but did not help

So this is occurring when you start on the 9.x version or on the Cloud version when you try to start the server? I assume the Cloud version since you are using Java 11. Also, does the error still occur when running the server from the command line? Ex: gwb runServer

This path clearly makes no sense: etc\C:\GW\CC\claimcenter\modules\configuration\build\idea\webapp\WEB-INF\jetty.xml.  Where does that come from?  Fix that.

The real reason for this error while starting the Jetty server is the presence of a whitespace character in either your root Guidewire directory or the IDEA_HOME path. Ensure that there are no spaces in either of these directories and preferably replace spaces with underscore (_) or get rid of them altogether. This error seems to be mysterious and impossible to debug at times but the root cause is always a whitespace character in the path. e.g. if your IDEA_HOME is pointing to C:/Program Files/Jetbrains/XXXX or if your root Guidewire folder is located in C:/Guidewire/Policy Center you will certainly encounter this error. The best way is to get rid of the space and use something like C:/Guidewire/PolicyCenter.
This issue occurs only while starting the Jetty server and everything else comes up fine. So probably it's due to the inability of Jetty jars to parse whitespaces in paths.

The failure was caused by a NodeJS dependency not available in the local machine. After installing NodeJS 16.x LTS version the issue disappeared. If you don't have NodeJS installed in your local running gwb compile will throw a node setup error.

I think you are mixing up two different issues. Nodejs required or a version mismatch is clearly echoed out by the gwb script. The error in question however is due to a different reason.

I did get a similar issue while setting up bc.
Please try the following steps:
If the server does not start due to "Illegal character" issue,
Then Create a new folder 'webapp' in
\modules\configuration\build\idea
Then copy all items from \webapps\bc
And paste them into the previously created folder (webapp)
And then restart the server
